# Unable to change directory in R Studio - problem with oneDrive

Tags: r, rstudio

I am facing a problem while trying to change directory to read a csv in Rstudio.

When I type `getwd()` I get this as my directory:

```
C:/Users/giorg/OneDrive/Υπολογιστής/MSc_Data_Science_&_CI/Introduction to Statistical methods for Data Science/Coursework
```

So when I try to read my csv I get that error:

```
C:/Users/giorg/OneDrive/ÕðïëïãéóôÞò/MSc_Data_Science_&_CI/Introduction to Statistical methods for Data Science/Coursework/x.csv': No such file or directory
```

I tried to change through Global options > General but I still have oneDrive in my path

And when I try with `setwd()` I get :

```
setwd("C:/Users/giorg/OneDrive/Υπολογιστής/Giorgos")
Error in setwd("C:/Users/giorg/OneDrive/<U+03A5>p<U+03BF><U+03BB><U+03BF><U+03B3><U+03B9>st<U+03AE><U+03C2>/Giorgos") 
  cannot change working directory
```

Any suggestions about what should I do?

Comment: How exactly are you reading the CSV? What command are you running?

Comment: I am using:

`require(readr)`

`x = read_csv("x.csv", col_names = F)`

Comment: @MrFlick I managed to get my wanted directory if I do it manually `setwd("C:/Users/giorg/Documents")` so my question is why I cannot change the directory through Rstudio and I always get the OneDrive in my path

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at some point. When I tried to change the directory I got the same error. In my case, the problem started when I changed the language of my computer. The file which I wanted to use as directory named in Greek language and after I turned my computer to English, R couldn't recognize it.
The problem solved when I renamed the file with English characters.